# Attempt to update array of object in mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Here is what I'm trying:

```
contactModel.update({
            'user_id': req.params.user_id,
            'contacts.contact_id': req.params.id
        }, {
            $set: {
                'contacts.$.name': req.body.contact.name,
                'contacts.$.phone_number': req.body.contact.phone_number
            }
        })
```

But the code is only for updating specific key. I want to update it based on dynamic key. If name is coming in req.body then it should update only name both are coming, so it should update both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fill dinamically the update object with keys found in req.body

```
   var obj = {};

   for(var i in req.body.contact){
     obj["contacts.$."+i] = req.body.contact[i];
   }

   contactModel.update({
        'user_id': req.params.user_id,
        'contacts.contact_id': req.params.id
    }, {
        $set: obj
    })
```